# store html on nfc tag

Tags: android, mobile, nfc

can NFC tags readers, especially on Android, open a webpage stored on the tag after being scanned?

I don't want to store a URL, I want to store a webpage in plain text and have that render after it is scanned. Is this supported?

```
<html><body>No signal? Bookmark this page!<img src="http://bit.ly/example"/>Test Image</img></body></html>
```

The above example is only 106 bytes, so can fit on most NFC tags, would this open in a webpage or can there be certain instructions to render it as a webpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the MIME type of the tag to `text/html`, it is possible that this will be rendered in browsers set up to read NFC tags containing that MIME type. Whether there are any such browsers, I cannot say. The AOSP Browser app does not support this -- the only NFC tags it supports are ones with `http` or `https` schemes for URLs, based on [the current contents of its manifest](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_browser/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml).

Answer (score 1):

EDITED ADDITIONAL INFO:

The Android Developer site at this link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc

contains a wealth of information which, upon reading, explains why this particular approach is challenging, but also inspires a while heap of other alternative ideas, methods, ways and means... I strongly recommend checking it out!!!

********** End Of Edit ************

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I have experimented with the very same, and created a custom NDEF message of MIME type text/html, with a fully coded HTML document as text in the data field of said MIME type ( & all standard tags such as  &  & so on). I have not had any luck with having the page rendered in a browser window. Usually, on scanning the NFC chip, it just returns a new-tag response showing my MIME "text/html" prefix, and completely omits the display of even the associated HTML encoding!

It's very frustrating..

However - in going to try again, as I understand that a recent release of Chrome Browser has a flag for experimental NFC features that can be activated.

In the Chrome Browser, navigate to chrome://chrome-urls and choose the flags link (or just go straight to chrome://flags ), then in the search bar type NFC. When the two or so options are presented, change the flags from default to enabled.

Now, I know that this then allows websites to interact with  data on NFC tags, and allows you to script the content fields as variables, etc etc etc, but I DON'T know if it will solve our "render MIME type text/html record as web page directly" problem.

I will test it out and let you know...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar thought to you and was investigating this idea. However android by default do not have an app that can recognize such tag by default... not even android chrome.

But what I did end up doing to explore this was to create an NFC tag project that can generate a tag with a mime record of `text/html` or `text/html+gzip` (FYI: `text/html+gzip` technically is not an officially registered mime record type, however I think it still keeps to the normal semantic of other mime record that combines a format + compression). It's located at https://github.com/mofosyne/js-ndef-html-tag to generate a tag.

As for viewing it, I've created an experimental android app where I have also placed an intent hook for both `text/html` or `text/html+gzip` so that any NFC tag with such content will automatically open up https://github.com/mofosyne/NFCMessageBoard and display the tag's html content.

However ideally you would push android to add native support for viewing html tags directly.

Until then, the official answer is no you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store a web page on an NFC tag - in fact you could store anything. That does not mean that it is a good idea. If you do not decide on the tags to be used, html is a bad idea. Rather store an URL and get the data online. Or store the data in a more compact format.

Comment: the assumption is that people won't always have internet connectivity. anyway if the browsers don't read it as we've already established already, then it isn't a viable idea